Problem exposing a SOAP service in Spring Boot: 404 error when trying to access the WSDL
I'm trying to setup a SOAP service in Spring Boot, but when I try to access the WSDL file (for example, http://localhost:8082/ws/AccountService.wsdl), I get a 404 (page not found) error:
I have the following configuration:
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "account")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema accountSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("AccountPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://example.com/accounts");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(accountSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema accountSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/AccountService.wsdl"));
    }
}

@Endpoint
public class AccountEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://example.com/accounts";

    private final AccountSoapService accountSoapService;

    public AccountEndpoint(AccountSoapService accountSoapService) {
        this.accountSoapService = accountSoapService;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "GetAccountRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetAccountResponse getAccount(@RequestPayload GetAccountRequest request) {
        // Chiamata al servizio per ottenere la risposta in base all'accountId
        return accountSoapService.getAccount(request.getAccountId());
    }
}

Found error of my configuration

It is a WSDL not a schema, next to that the wsdl in your config is named account not AccountService as it will use the name of the bean. YOu should ditch the accountSchema bean, replace the DefaultWsdl11Definition with a SimpleWsdl11Definition to expose the static wsdl you have.

i have replaced the bean with this:
@Bean(name = "AccountService")
public SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition() {
SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/AccountService.wsdl"));
return simpleWsdl11Definition;
}
is it correct?

Don't add code as comments that is totally unreadable. Changing and testing the code should be easy enough.

Yes, I'm sorry but since this change wasn't successful I wanted to ask you if you had made the right correction

It is the right correct. Do you hnave an @EnableWs as well? As that is needed for the infrastructure, unless you are using Spring Boot but then this @Configuration doesn't make sense.

no but I just added it in this class along with @configuration but I still get not found

Do you physically have that wsdl at all? Are things being bootstrapped? Ditch this class as well as the @EnableWs. Add spring.webservices.path=/ws and spring.webservices.wsdl-locations=classpath:/wsdl/ (assuming the wsdl is in the correct src/main/resources/wsdl directory`. Spring Boot will take care of setting up Spring Web Services.

yes perfect, now I see my file, thank you very much

sorry to bother you again but I'm trying an api soap and I get this error message:
Error occurred during jwt authentication: Request processing failed: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/xml. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?

Don't ask another question in an already answered question.

There are 2 problems with this configuration and 1 with the call.

You are using a DefaultWsdl11Definition where you should have used a SimpleWsdl11Definition
You are working around the features that Spring Boot provides you.
The WSDL will be available with <bean-name>.wsdl and your bean is named account not AccountService.

You can fix basically everything by removing the whole WebServiceConfig and add the following to your application.properties.
spring.webservices.path=/ws
spring.webservices.wsdl-locations=classpath:/wsdl/

This will let Spring Boot automatically configure Spring Web Services and expose the WSDL with the correct name.
